# Trailing slash at the end of permalink loads faster / better SEO?

Tags: permalinks

Is it true that if you put a trailing slash at the end of the permalink, it would load faster for a single or a multisite WordPress post? Also, is this better for SEO?

Answer (score 2):

If the permalink is to a file with an extension, no trailing slash is needed.

```
http://www.domain.com/afile.html
```

If the permalink is to a directory, a trailing slash is preferred. Otherwise, the server will respond with a redirect and the browser will have to add the trailing slash and make a second request automatically.

```
http://www.domain.com/adirectory/    is served immediately by the server

http://www.domain.com/adirectory     browser must make a second request with trailing slash
```